# Azure cannot access an image from asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, azure

I cannot access an image that is reside beside the asp.net page.Access is denied any hint?

Comment: access an image in a src tag or via code? Are you sure it's actually there? (maybe remote desktop in and look at the filesystem?)

Comment: I am accessing it with page_load not a tag

Comment: The IIS in cloud doesnot support directory browsing due to security issues. Is it a 403.14 you are getting?

Comment: Access to the path 'XXXXXXXXlogo.png' is denied

Comment: Are you using Azure Websites or Azure Cloud Services?

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled local storage in the configs?

from the article:

> local storage in the cloud is not the same as that under our local
>   IIS environment.  Local storage, is assumed under an ASP.NET
>   application running on a local IIS server.  In the Azure world, you
>   must first configure your role to request local storage as it is
>   deployed.  This can be done with the Role Editor in VS

Read more: http://www.intertech.com/Blog/Post/Windows-Azure-Local-File-Storage-How-To-Guide-and-Warnings.aspx#ixzz2I7xrJiBD

http://www.intertech.com/Blog/Post/Windows-Azure-Local-File-Storage-How-To-Guide-and-Warnings.aspx

Comment: up vote but I am looking for something that allow me to host my 100% asp.net website to azure without changing too much. also I do not want to use any Azure specific features.